# iPhone 5 won't activate without SIM card

Tags: iphone

I just purchased an unlocked iPhone 5 from the Apple store today, and I can't activate it to use it because it says "please" insert a valid SIM card to use it. I'm not using this phone as a "phone" to make calls. I'm a developer and am just looking to use it for development purposes. How can I go about using the iOS 5?

Comment: Since it is a unlocked phone stick any SIM card in it.

Comment: What if I don't have a SIM card?

Comment: than add that important requirement to your question.

Comment: You need a SIM card to activate the device.  See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/764/iphone-stuck-at-no-sim-card-installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot activate an iPhone 5 without (nano) SIM card. You could go to a local store and ask if they have one for you just to activate and you're fine to go.

There is no point in buying a SIM card if you don't have plans to use it as phone.

Comment: I tried setting the phone into DFU mode, but it wouldn't let me bypass it, so I ordered a cheap sim card from amazon. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Sorry :3 Totally spaced on this one.